# How to display arabic and kurdish text instead of question marks android

Tags: php, android

I am developing an app that will display text in three languages. I am getting data from server via PHP scripts. The problem is that arabic and kurdish text shows up as ? marks. I have modified the code to accept utf-8 characters. The data shows up as ? marks even when opened in browser. The collation of the mysql server is utf8. Also I have added kurdish and arabic text statically to my app and it works perfectly. I have also tried utf8_encode() without any results -

```
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
//          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
//                  .getContent()));
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }

            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();

            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong in my code? Or do I need to do something else? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am using the following php script to encode json data -

```
$subcat_id = mysql_real_escape_string(intval($_GET["id"]));
$query = mysql_query("select * from subcategory where category_id = $subcat_id")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
```

and the collation used on the mysql server is utf8. Thanks again.

Comment: u have to store arabic and kurdish text in db..then u can get easily

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am fetching data from online database server and the data includes arabic and kurdish text.

Comment: u are getting data from database..which are right for other language?

Comment: yes. The encoding of database is utf-8.

Comment: If you open the url with the browser of your device, what does it show?

Comment: It shows question marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $connect); after making database connection
for example -

```
$connect = mysql_connect(dbhost, user, password) or 
                         die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $connect)
```